# Webservice response in IOS 7 is giving recently fetch data

Tags: ios7

I am facing an problem. when i'm hitting web services in IOS 7 then i'm getting previously fetch data of same request while if i hit same request on browser then get updated data , that is different from the data that i'm getting in ios 7. I also check on my server but there is no such data available on server that i'm getting in ios 7.

Any one know about this problem..?

Is this IOS version problem or My server problem..?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code that fetches the data.

Comment: problem has been solved. Actually problem is of caching data.